# how to change html elements by if condition in body of html

Tags: html, laravel

i am biginner , in body of html i have a input that filled by table row clicking:

```
<input id="office_id" disabled>
```

i want to place diffrent tag in body by value of office_id,if has value ,call PUT method and if is null value in office_id call POST method:

```
@if (?????)
     <form method="POST" action="{{ route('office.store') }}">
          <button type="submit" id="saveBtn" class="btn btn-warning" style="width: 95px;"> save</button>
      </form>
@else
     <form method="PUT" action="{{ route('office.update',$office->office_id) }}">
           <button type="submit" id="saveBtn" class="btn btn-warning" style="width: 95px;"> update</button>
     </form>
 @endif
```

What code should I write inside the if condition?

Comment: if(!$office->office_id)

Comment: since you are using blade templates you can do something like this ```@if (!empty($office->office_id))```

Answer (score 0):

In this code the **empty()** function is used to check if the **office_id** is empty or not. If it's empty, it means you're creating a new office, so the form uses the **POST** method and directs to the **office.store** route. If it's not empty, it means you're updating an existing office, so the form uses the POST method with the **@method('PUT')** directive to override the method and directs to the **office.update** route with the specific **office_id**.

```
@if (empty($office->office_id))
    <form method="POST" action="{{ route('office.store') }}">
        <button type="submit" id="saveBtn" class="btn btn-warning" style="width: 95px;">Save</button>
    </form>
@else
    <form method="POST" action="{{ route('office.update', $office->office_id) }}">
        @method('PUT') {{-- Add this line to specify the method as PUT --}}
        <button type="submit" id="saveBtn" class="btn btn-warning" style="width: 95px;">Update</button>
    </form>
@endif
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code has a few problems besides your question: I will try addressing both in my answer:

### Security

Whenever working with forms, always make sure `@csrf` is present in your form to prevent potential XSS attacks.

### Solution

Since you use blade templates you can conditionally use just one form to fulfil both the condifitons:

```
<form id="officeForm" method="{{ !empty($office->office_id) ? 'PUT' : 'POST' }}"
      action="{{ !empty($office->office_id) ? route('office.update', $office->office_id) : route('office.store') }}">
    @csrf
    @if(!empty($office->office_id))
        @method('PUT')
    @endif
    <button type="submit" id="saveBtn" class="btn btn-warning" style="width: 95px;">
        {{ !empty($office->office_id) ? 'Update' : 'Save' }}
    </button>
</form>
```